# When clicking on an anchor element: is there any event triggered on the target element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I face the following problem:

I have an anchor element `<a href="#target">TARGET</a>`
and a target element `<div id="target">content</div>`.

What I want to do is call a method **defined on the target element**.

The reason for this criteria is based on the need to call the method even if the link is coming from another subpage.

My first idea before research was the `<div id="target" focus="myMethod">content</div>` event, but that doesn't trigger.

Then I started my research on 
[W3schools HTML a tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)
and [the jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/)
as well as [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) ofc. but I didn't find any related posts (maybe due to the hillarious amount of questions regarding "how to trigger a element's click event").

I appreciate any ideas, spend quite some time on it :(

Comment: I don't think any event is triggered on the target element. Maybe you should use the `hashchange` event?

Comment: Clicking on the link doesn't focus on the target, it just scrolls to it.

Comment: I considered listening on the scroll event in connection with target element reaching view, but that would get out of hand pretty soon if I need this on multiple target elements

Comment: Listen for hashchange, and then check the current hash.

Comment: I'm gonna try the `hashchange` event and report later

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `hashchange` event, and then trigger a custom event of your own on the target event.

```
$(document).on("hashchange", function() {
    $(window.location.hash).trigger("linkedto");
});

$("#target1").on("linkedto", function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the function name of your method for each element in a `data-method` attribute (in order to avoid defining the method as a custom property on the HTML element itself, which is considered bad practice by some due to the possibility of side effects).

Then listen to the `hashchange` event as well as the page load to find the element corresponding to the current hash value and call its method. *Note: I used `this` instead of `window` for calling the method function in order to be scope-agnostic.*

```js
// the method you want to be called when the page jumps to the element:
function contentElementMethod() {
  console.log("the hash corresponds to the #content element!");
}

// the handler for getting the element corresponding to the current location hash and calling the method defined in its [data-method] attribute
function hashElementHandler() {
  if (!window.location.hash) return; // we don't want to fire the first method found when there's no location hash set, e.g. when the page loads without one
  
  var hashEl = document.querySelector(window.location.hash + '[data-method]');
  if(hashEl) {
    this[hashEl.getAttribute('data-method')]();
  }
}

// listen to the hash change event
window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashElementHandler);

// also check the page hash on page load (wrap this 
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', hashElementHandler);
```

```html
<p><a href="#target">TARGET</a></p>
<div id="target" data-method="contentElementMethod">content</div>
```